# How to download Zip File from an s3 bucket to a local directory within a node.js lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, amazon-s3, lambda

I am trying to grab a zip file from s3 and store it in a local directory and then read that directory to ensure that the zip.file is there. Is there a sure-fire way to do this. When I read to see if the file is located in the tmp directory it is not there.

```
// MAKE DIRECTORIES FOR ZIPPED AND UNZIPPED FOLDER
const zipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localZippedFolder, { recursive: true });
const unZipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localUnzippedFolder, { recursive: true });

// VERIFY THAT DIRECTORIES ARE CREATED
const zipFolderChecker = fs.statSync(zipDirFolder);
const unZipFolderChecker = fs.statSync(unZipDirFolder);
console.log('SUCCESS: 2 DIRECTORIES CREATED');

// CREATE STREAMS FOR S3 BUCKET OBJECTS
const tempFileName = path.join(zipDirFolder, 'downloaded.zip');
const tempFileDownload = fs.createWriteStream(tempFileName);

// DOWNLOAD ZIP FILE FROM S3 BUCKET TO TEMP FOLDER
const getS3Object = await s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(tempFileDownload);
console.log('SUCCESS: ZIP FILE DOWNLOADED');

// LIST FILES IN ZIP FOLDER DIRECTORY
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(zipDirFolder, (error, files) => {
        error ? reject(error) : resolve(files);
        console.log(files)
```

any examples on how to fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

based on AWS documentation : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/requests-using-stream-objects.html .

Your code is almost  correct, the issue with waiting of end of downloading process. Could you add debugging information in your code :

```
const s3Stream = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
    s3Stream.on('error', function(err) {
        // NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist
        console.error(err);
    });
    // there is the main debugging point
    s3Stream.pipe(tempFileDownload).on('error', function(err) {
        // capture any errors that occur when writing data to the file
        console.error('File Stream:', err);
    }).on('close', function() {
        console.log('Done.');
    });
```

Also  your stream is closed not after `await` statement but `on('close', () => {})` event. You need to convert it to promise:

```
async getObjectToFile(bucket, key):Promise<void> {     
        return new Promise<void>((res, rej) => {
            // *
            // *
           //your code
s3Stream.pipe(tempFileDownload).on('error', function(err) {
            // capture any errors that occur when writing data to the file
            console.error('File Stream:', err);
            rej(err) ;
        }).on('close', function() {
            console.log('Done.');
            res()
        });

        });
    };
```

Comment: running this returns an unexpected identifier error.

Comment: when i run my original code it doesn't return any error however it also does not download the zip file to the tmp directory

Comment: per the documentation, i know that you can do streams with an image file but my question is can you write a zip file to a temp directory in the same fashion

Comment: it does not matter downloading type of file. Could you provide whole error ?

Comment: okay so the error that I get back from the s3.stream.pipe is:

2020-03-11 11:25:07.030 File Stream: [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/tmp/ZippedStudentData']

Comment: it seems  application does not have necessary permissions for creating folder or files in `tmp` folder. Could you wrap your `await` method calls with try catch ?

Comment: in general case folder is not existed in moment when you try to pipe AWS S3 object with file stream.